# Error TypeError: cannot set property "name" of undefined ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I get this error when trying to submit my form, it used to work fine, after a while on working on some other feature this apparently happened. Been looking around for hours and have not found a solution yet. I do not know why this is happening, I tried initializing the component in the constructor as well as in the ngoninit lifecycle, but it still did not work. I can not see why this error is occurring, everything is supposed to be working, would love if someone could help me.

This is the error I get;

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
    at RecipeService.searchRecipes (recipe.service.ts:43)
    at RecipeSearchComponent.onSubmit (recipe-search.component.ts:33)
    at RecipeSearchComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_8_listener (recipe-search.component.html:10)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21772)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21814)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:37027)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)`

This is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-search',
  templateUrl: './recipe-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-search.component.scss']
})
export class RecipeSearchComponent implements OnInit {


    // initilization of the form
  searchForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    minCalories: ["0", Validators.required],
    maxCalories: ["1500", Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService, private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  // submit function that calls the searchRecipes function from the recipe service
  onSubmit() {
    const minCalories = +this.searchForm.get("minCalories").value;
    const maxCalories = +this.searchForm.get("maxCalories").value;
    const name = this.searchForm.get("name").value;
    this.recipeService.searchRecipes(1, minCalories, maxCalories, name);
    this.router.navigate(["recipes"]);
  }
}
```

This is the html

```html
<section class="search">
  <div class="search__box">
    <div class="search__box--wrapper">
      <h1 class="search__box--title">Search</h1>
      <p class="search__box--paragraph">We Find Your Dream Recipes</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="search__form--box">
    <form class="search__form" [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="search__group search__group--title">
        <input
        placeholder="Enter Any Title..."
        class="search__input search__input--title"
        type="text"
        formControlName="name"
        required
        minlength="3"
        >

      <small
        class="search__input--title--small"
        [ngClass]="{'name--red': !searchForm['controls'].name.valid}"
        >
        Must be least 3 Characters long!
      </small>

        <label class="search__label search__label--title" for="title">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="search__calories--box">
        <div class="search__group search__group--calories">
          <input
          placeholder="Min Calories"
          type="number"
          class="search__input search__input--calories"
          formControlName="minCalories"
          required>
          <label class="search__label" for="minCalories">Min</label>
        </div>
        <div class="search__group search__group--calories">
          <input
          placeholder="Max Calories"
          type="number"
          class="search__input search__input--calories"
          formControlName="maxCalories"
          required
          >
          <label class="search__label" for="maxCalories">Max</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="search__button" [disabled]="!searchForm.valid">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have reproduced your code here  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-wx9yvr  but didn't got any error.. Can you fork the stackblitz and reproduce the error??

Comment: what have you seen when debugging in the browser console? especially in onSubmit function?

Comment: That was the error Silva, the one i posted in the beginning, gonna have a look at ur stackblitz Murugan

Answer (score 0):

try this in your ngOnInit

```
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])],
    minCalories: ["0", Validators.required],
    maxCalories: ["1500", Validators.required]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue in the service, recipe service, so this had actually nothing to do with the form, sorry for the late answer. thanks for everyone who watched and tried.